# Jumping back and forth in XMonad window history

Tags: xmonad

It's possible to use `XMonad.Actions.GroupNavigation` as
explained at

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Actions-GroupNavigation.html

to bind a key to the previously active window.  But, if you press
this key twice, you simply return to the point of departure,
since that becomes the new previous history item after the first
jump.  Is it possible to go back in history more than one step?
It would be nice to have one key for going back and one for
going forwards.